# Docker: can't run hello-world. Windows 10

Tags: docker, windows-10

I'm a newbie in docker. I try to run

```
$ docker run hello-world
```

And I got this error:

```
$ docker run hello-world
    Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
    Pulling repository docker.io/library/hello-world
    C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Network timed out while trying to connect to https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/hello-world/images. You may want to check your internet connection or if you are behind a proxy..
    See 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe run --help'.
```

Also I allowed all points for this app in firewall
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwx0j.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into that issue while moving from mac to windows. I would recommend to check the following things:

- How many network adapters do you have? Check if there are too many and if docker is using the correct one. In case you have too many - delete the one which is not being used
- for some people the network protocol IP6 needed to be deactivated to get docker to talk to the internet
- check your traffic on the network adapter - in case you are using hyper-v you need to make sure that the network adapter is allowed to use the one which is connected to the internet

I hope this gave you a notch into the right direction.

Comment: The problem is solved. 
I've turned off hyper-v on my pc, after that I've removed all this hyper-v adapters and turned on hyper-v. After that all works fine.

Comment: thanks - glad it worked out for you - for the first steps it is very easy to get entangled in pitfalls like hyperv vs other virtual environments as well as the IP / docker network settings ... keep trying - it is a great piece of software.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue on windows 10 by resetting the DNS server to use the Google DNS fixed address: 8.8.8.8 ([docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#network))

[image]

Comment: Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question.*

Answer (score 0):

After installing the docker for windows, I got the error as below.

PS C:\Users<Username>> docker run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers).

So made changes in docker > Settings > Resources > Network > updated docker subnet to
10.0.75.0/24.

It worked like charm after.